# Is there a way to convert .doc files to pdf or jpg on a host like GoDaddy?

Tags: .net, pdf, .doc

And can this be done without a really expensive solution like Apose? That costs way more than I can possibly spend.

Essentially, I need to be able to let someone upload a document and retain its formatting to display it through flex. If there's another way to do that, I'd appreciate a solution to that as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out LiveDocx: http://www.phplivedocx.org/2009/02/06/convert-doc-to-pdf-in-php/

```
$phpLiveDocx = new Zend_Service_LiveDocx_MailMerge();

$phpLiveDocx->setUsername('username')
            ->setPassword('password');

$phpLiveDocx->setLocalTemplate('document.doc');

// necessary as of LiveDocx 1.2
$phpLiveDocx->assign('dummyFieldName', 'dummyFieldValue');

$phpLiveDocx->createDocument();

$document = $phpLiveDocx->retrieveDocument('pdf');

file_put_contents('document.pdf', $document);

unset($phpLiveDocx);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try [bullzip](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php), which they have a programming interface via ActiveX/COM, the onus is on your part to select the bullzip pdf printer and submitting the document to be converted into pdf.

**Edit:** Here's a [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/giospdfnetlibrary.aspx) to another library code on Codeproject. And here's another library called ITextSharp found [here](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/), the tutorial to using this is found on CodeProject also, [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/iTextSharpPdfTables.aspx), and another [source](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Java/Creating-Simple-PDF-Files-With-iTextSharp/) on how to create a simple PDF using the aforementioned library.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

If you know perl, check out [jpg2pdf](http://freshmeat.net/projects/jpg2pdf)

<strike>I'm not sure what this is writen in, but give it a try: [Doc2pdf](http://freshmeat.net/projects/doc2pdf)</strike>